# button_to to render pdf format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button-to

In my controller I have the action:

```
def booking_sheet_report
  @groups = Group.all.order('priority DESC')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv
    format.pdf
  end
end
```

and in the view I want the user to be able to open (download) the format.pdf when clicking on a button_to element (I do have a booking_sheet_report.pdf.erb view). With a link_to (`<%= link_to 'PDF', booking_sheet_report_path(format: :pdf) %>`) works fine.

I tried the followings without any success:

```
<%= button_to "PDF", {action: "booking_sheet_report",  :form => { "data-type" => "pdf" }}, {class: 'btn-u', method: :get} %>


<%= button_to "PDF", {action: "booking_sheet_report(format: :pdf)",  :form => { "data-type" => "pdf" }}, {class: 'btn-u', method: :get} %>
```

The second one gives an error: `No route matches {:action=>"booking_sheet_report(format: :pdf)", :controller=>"reports", :form=>{"data-type"=>"pdf"}}`

Any clue how is this possible or what I am doing wrong?

Edit: the one relevant route is `get 'booking_sheet_report' => 'reports#booking_sheet_report'`

Comment: What is the error? Update it in your question.

Comment: Show the routs file.

Comment: Try `<%= button_to "PDF", {action: "booking_sheet_report(format: :pdf)"},  :form => { "data-type" => "pdf" }, {class: 'btn-u', method: :get} %>`

Comment: @Pavan I get a syntax error on that one.

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik putting the one relevant route now. No route for pdf really.

Comment: What is the syntax error? Can ou paste it here?

Comment: @Pavan syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...class: 'btn-u', method: :get} );@output_buffer.safe_append='
...                               ^

Comment: Ok. Using parenthesis is always tricky. Try this `<%= button_to "PDF", booking_sheet_report_path(format: :pdf), class: 'btn-u', method: :get, :form => {"data-type" => "pdf" } %>`

Comment: it worked, thank you. just changed the booking_sheet_report to booking_sheet_report_path

Comment: I almost forgot that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No route matches {:action=>"booking_sheet_report(format: :pdf)",
>   :controller=>"reports", :form=>{"data-type"=>"pdf"}}

```
<%= button_to "PDF", {action: "booking_sheet_report(format: :pdf)",  :form => { "data-type" => "pdf" }}, {class: 'btn-u', method: :get} %>
```

The problem with above code is you are closing the parenthesis(`}`) at the wrong side. I mean the closing parenthesis for `:action =>` is placed on the wrong side. So it is considering the whole thing as ***url option*** and that is reported as a no route error. Also using parenthesis is always tricky.

> button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
>   public

The following should work

```
<%= button_to "PDF", booking_sheet_report_path(format: :pdf), class: 'btn-u', method: :get, :form => {"data-type" => "pdf" } %>
```